# Повторяются записи при запросе. SQL. PHP

Tags: php, sql

Пользователь подписывается на определенные категории новостей. Например, на чемпионат Эстонии и на клуб Челси.
Категории делятся на 2 таблицы. Чемпионаты и клубы. И вот когда я делаю запрос вывода новостей только по выбранным категориям пользователя, некоторые новости повторяются, так как новость может принадлежать нескольким категориям. Как обойти это повторение?

```
SELECT * from `news` n1
join `posts_clubs` on n1.news_id=posts_clubs.id_news  
join `subscription_teams` on posts_clubs.id_club = subscription_teams.team_id
WHERE subscription_teams.user_id =30
UNION 
SELECT * from `news` n1
join `posts_champs` on n1.news_id=posts_champs.id_news  
join `subscription_champs` on posts_champs.id_champ = subscription_champs.champ_id
WHERE subscription_champs.user_id=30 ORDER BY `pubdate` DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Union не удаляет дубликаты, т.к. у вас `select *`.
Вам нужны, как я понял, только инфо из news, а остальная инфа не нужна. `select n1.*` - тогда дублей не будет.
И совет, делайте временные таблицы, не старайтесь всё в одном запросе написать.

Comment: То, что нужно. Благодарю!